# css pseudo down arrow :after not showing up on all <section> tags

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am assigning a unique ID to each `<section>` tag that will display a :after pseudo down arrow indicator on my pages. For instance...

```
#welcome {
    background-color: #007ee5;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

#welcome:after {
    content: "";
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:30px solid transparent;
    border-right:30px solid transparent;
    border-top:31px solid #007ee5;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

The above code works fine and I get the desired outcome for the id="welcome" `<section id="welcome">` tag.

Here is the page: [my page](http://michaelachoate.com/)

When I add another ID to another `<section id="example">` tag further down the page it shows up but it disappears from the other  tag????

I would like a down arrow indicator after each section with different colors to match.

I've tried a couple of different appraoches that come close but, I'm not getting the desired effect.

Is it something in the cascade? I've tried a global element for the `<section>` tag but, I am not able to change the indicator colors to match each section.

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: I'm using the above code.

Comment: FOr instance, the above code would be identical with a different ID and color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply `position: relative` to subsequent sections, it's changing their `z-index`. Apply a `z-index` to your `:after` pseudo class.

E.g. `z-index: 100`

```
#welcome:after {
    content: "";
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:30px solid transparent;
    border-right:30px solid transparent;
    border-top:31px solid #007ee5;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That did it. Never would have guessed z-index would affect that. Thank you, Sir!